# A table with col A and col B have many vs. many relationship, how do I find a distinct value in col. A with a specific value in co.B?

Tags: sql

```
| Company  | Location       |
|:--------:|:--------------:|
| Firm A   | Location 1     |
| Firm A   | Location 2     |
| Firm B   | Location 2     |
| Firm B   | Location 4     |
| Firm C   | Location 3     |
| Firm C   | Location 5     |
```

How can I pick Firm A & B by "looking for a company which has not facility in location 2"?
Expected result: Find a company without location in "Location 2", the query gives:

```
|Company  |
|:--------|
|Firm C   |
```

Comment: Please include the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, added the expected query resuts

Comment: Uh, right, bad example, actually my situation is to find the reverse, which means a company "does not have" facility in location 3.  Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anti-join or you can use `NOT EXISTS`. An example of the latter is:

```
select *
from my_table a
where not exists (
  select 1 from my_table b 
  where b.company = a.company and b.location = 'Location 2'
)
```

Comment: Weird, I made mock up table and this works, but on my real table (with more columns) it still include Firm B in result, what could be the reason?
In real table, for instance Firm B has 5 locations, the query gives me 4 Firm B in the results.  Which means it ruled out "Firm B - Location 2" but picked "Firm B - Location 4", "Firm B - Location 5", "Firm B - Location 6", "Firm B - Location 7"

Comment: Now I got it, the problem is in column "Location", the value are reference from another table, it stored the reference table col. B value but show col. A value, so I use col. A value in the query and it didn't work, changed to col. B value and it works.